# Manage vertical levels rendering

Tags: unity, shaders

I've been working on a semi-professionnal project for more than one year.
The game is in 3D with a TopView camera.
In this game, the player will be in very vertical spaces, with lots of ladder and stairs.

The actual problem is that I need to show only what is at the actual height of the player.

I have made a shader that 'cut' the objects above a given height.

The problem is that my mesh are open above this height, and we just see nothing inside.

If you have any idea on how to make something to fill an open mesh or any other system that will do the job, i'll be very pleased to read you :)

This is what I have
[image]

This is what I aim to (black above top of walls) 
[image: http://media.moddb.com/images/mods/1/25/24369/2013-12-31_00001.jpg]

Comment: The edit has been made :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Similar problem: rendering sliced volumes with solid inside

I recall a similar situation to your problem, but can't find it anymore. The user wanted to render sliced volumes, but when he just cut the polygons as you did he got the empty space problem as well.

A solution would be to disable backface culling and draw backfaces in a solid color, independant of lighting.

## Backface culling

Backface culling is a technique to speed up rendering. Every polygon can be considered to have two sides, a front side and a back side. Whether the *backface* or the *frontface* is facing the camera, is decided by the winding order of the vertices (https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling). You can then use *backface culling* to only draw polygons facing the camera. This effectively cuts the number of polygons to render in two.

This is the reason you are seeing an "open mesh" as you describe it. The polygons of the wall are facing to the outside. Polygons on the inside are culled. Normally this is not a problem, as you can't see inside of closed volumes, unless you place the camera inside of the object. However when you have open volumes (e.g. through a slicing shader), the insides can become visible, and the "trick" of leaving out the backfaces becomes a problem.

## Solution to your problem

So in summary, you could draw the backfaces of of all volumes that can be sliced by your shader. I would render them in a solid black color, unaffected by lighting, to achieve the effect in your reference screenshot.

One small caveat: if your floor plane intersects the walls at the bottom, it may end up showing through. You could solve this by "closing" the wall meshes at the bottom, by using a bottom quad that lies slightly above the floor. It won't be visible for unsliced walls, and for slices walls it'll give you a nice black bottom, without the floor shining through.

**EDIT:** been Googling around for a while, and the terms used to describe this problem are "capping sliced/cut meshes/geometry/volumes". It should also be possible with the stencil buffer, but I don't have much experience with it myself. Found these pages, but they are quite dated:

https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/advanced/advanced97/notes/node10.html

https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/144180-Using-the-stencil-buffer-to-cap-solids

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quality of your answer, I will now try to add this into my game, if it works I would probably post the result here :)

Answer (score 0):

Close your walls mesh and just paint it plain black on the texture